# In bash, is there a way to echo/print the last stdout? Is there a variable that stdout is assigned to?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In bash, is there a way to echo/print the last stdout? Is there a variable that stdout is assigned to?

I don't want to redirect the output. I just want to be able to read/print it after a command is run.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope, there's no way to see a line sent to `stdout` unless `stdout`'s already been sent somewhere. If it was sent to a console, copy the text from that console. If you sent it to a file, `tail -n 1` that file. If you can re-run the command which generates the line you want to see, I would suggest piping it to `tail -n 1` to see just the last line of output.

Bash keeps a history of executed commands (`~/.bash_history` by default in GNU Bash 4.2), but not of output.

Comment: Thanks. I guess there's no native way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding `|tee output` to the end of your command.

If you want to capture the terminal output of your entire session, try [script(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script).

Also, [this questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923144/alternatives-to-bash-shell-or-zshrc/6979238#6979238) is looking for the ability to search command output, so check answers there too.